# Angular2 rc1 Router does not recognize url parameters

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a simple component with the following route:

```
{ path: '/',  component: ListComponent }
```

I access it using "/list" url. Now i'm trying to add some url parameters like this:

```
this.router.navigate(
  ['/list',
    {page: page, perPage: this.perPage}]
);
```

The url changes to the following:

```
/list;page=2;perPage=10
```

And i have the code to fetch these parameters:

```
routerOnActivate(curr: RouteSegment): void {
    console.log('router activate', curr);
}
```

The problems:

- when i execute the router.navigate() - routerOnActivate isn't getting called, but the url changes
- if i try to enter the url manually - routerOnActivate is executed, but the RouteSegment does not see any of my arguments in the url

What am i doing wrong?

**UPDATE** I've noticed that when i try to navigate to /list;page=2... - the routerOnActivate is getting called on the parent router and the arguments can be accessed from there.

Comment: I think passing query parameters is not yet supported in the new router (not sure though).

Comment: It works fine if i have a route like /list/:id and then pass in other route params to it as well. But it doesn't seem to work for simple /list route

Comment: For `/list/:id` you shouldn't pass an object for `id`, just the value. And yes, such parameters are already supported.

Comment: And i am passing ['/list/listId', { additional_args }] - this works

Comment: Ok, that's what I mean't with "shouldn't pass an object for `id`"